# Missing "description" for get user playlists

Tags: deezer

It seems missing the "description" attribute of the playlist object when i request this endpoint http://developers.deezer.com/api/user/playlists

So, no way to get it in this way ? Must doing a request for each of this playlist ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you have to retrieve it with the /playlist/id.

Comment: That cost a lot to perf... No improvement in the future for that ?

Comment: It is not planned for now, unfortunately